# ThreeJs different Text on each face of cube

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm working on Threejs to animate a cube with different text on each cube faces. I used DynamicTexture to place text on cube faces, but it places same text on each side of cube. I don't know how to place different text on each side. Is there any way to do is and place text on runtime by user inputs? Thanks.

Main.js

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(4, 4, 4);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById('display').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
var dynamictexture = new THREEx.DynamicTexture(512, 512);
dynamictexture.context.font = "bolder 90px verdana";
dynamictexture.texture.needsUpdate = true;
dynamictexture.clear('#d35400').drawText('Text', undefined, 256, 'green');
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: dynamictexture.texture, opacity:1, 
transparent: true});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
controls.update();
dynamictexture.texture
renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();
```

Comment: Can you please regenerate the issue in a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: [link] (https://codepen.io/manivannabalaji/pen/eYmdQjr) here's the codepen link

Comment: given link is not working properly..

Comment: Link work's fine for me. I'm new to codepen, let me know if code is editable for you or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)` to accomplish this. All you need to do is pass an array containing the materials and specifying the map for each of the faces.

```
var face_textures = [];
function createFaceTextures() {
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var dynamictexture = new THREEx.DynamicTexture(512, 512);
    dynamictexture.context.font = "bolder 90px verdana";
    dynamictexture.texture.needsUpdate = true;
    dynamictexture.clear('#d35400').drawText(i.toString(), undefined, 256, 'green');
    face_textures.push(dynamictexture);
  }
}
createFaceTextures();

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(4, 4, 4);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById('display').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
var dynamictexture = new THREEx.DynamicTexture(512, 512);
dynamictexture.context.font = "bolder 90px verdana";
dynamictexture.texture.needsUpdate = true;
dynamictexture.clear('#d35400').drawText('Text', undefined, 256, 'green');
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2,);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: dynamictexture.texture, opacity:1, transparent: true});

var materials = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: face_textures[0].texture}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: face_textures[1].texture}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: face_textures[2].texture}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: face_textures[3].texture}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: face_textures[4].texture}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: face_textures[5].texture})
];

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
scene.add(cube);
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    dynamictexture.texture
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but it shows a warning 'MeshFaceMaterial' has been removed. Is there any alternate material available that works like this?

Comment: Edited the post, should have no warnings now @manivannabalaji